# How to avoid a blink when UIWebView loads HTML

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

I have a native iOS app that contains a tab bar. The view controller for each tab contains a UIWebView. When the user switches between tabs, I load the HTML in the corresponding web view. The HTML is fully cached on a device. Here is how I feed the HTML to UIWebView:

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseUrl];
```

baseUrl is a file URL pointing to a directory where all assets are located.

This works great in online and offline modes, however it takes time for the UIWebView to parse and render the HTML. As a result, the user sees a brief blink of a white background when switching between tabs. I'd like to remove it, because the user is able to tell that the UI is not native (native UI renders instantly).

I was thinking about taking a screenshot of the UIWebView once it's done rendering the HTML and caching it in memory. The next time the user navigates to that web view, the app displays the screenshot while the UIWebView is rendering the HTML in the background. Finally, the app swaps the screen shot with the actual UIWebView and takes a new screenshot. This is similar to how Google Chrome app works.

Does anyone know a better solution to this problem?

Comment: What I do is put up a spinning activity view until the web view has finished loading; this covers the delay psychologically. - Of course another option would be not to use a UIWebView in this way; now that Text Kit is here you can do some really powerful layout of text and images that way.

Comment: Spinner will work, however it will blink too, since in most cases the HTML will be rendered pretty fast. My goal is to avoid the blink.

Comment: OK, how about this: don't show the UIWebView at all until it has finished loading, and when it has, fade it into view. Again, this is just psychological trickery, intended to ease the jarring sense; but such trickery does work.

Comment: Yeah, that's one solution. I also need to show something until the web view is ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you present that web view. I'm not really sure from your description how you do it, but since you're talking about a blink of white background, I'm going to assume there is a situation where you have a web view with a loaded html and then you switch it to another html. The solution for that case would be:

- create a second web view,
- load the new html to this new web view,
- when that web view finishes loading html (you can find out if you use UIWebViewDelegate) you can then quickly switch it with your old web view (meaning you finally add the new web view to the view hierarchy at THIS point, not when you created it).

This way you'll have an instant switch between old and new html, however user will be left waiting and it is your decision what to do with it. You could use UIActivityIndicatorView for example.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. That's not quite what I'm looking for. I added more details to my question.

Comment: Well if you want the html to be visible right after clicking on tab bar, you just have to keep one UIWebView for each item on the bar and load the html early (at application start?), I can't think of another way to make it always ready to display.

Answer (score 0):

When `webViewDidFinishLoad:` gets called you can do any number of things, make the webview visible, remove something that you had on top of the webview etc...